# QgsVectorFileWriter write kml qgis-3 with sybmology

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

for yeaars in QGIS-2 I used the code below successfully to write a kml with symbology  ,
but in QGIS-3 just can't get it to work, layernew is a QgsVectorLayer

```
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layernew)

#QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layernew])
mySymbol1=QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'color':'#ffffff','color_border':linecolor,'width_border':linethickness})myRenderer  = layernew.rendererV2()

myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)

layernew.triggerRepaint()

symstyle = QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology    
#saveoptions=QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()   
#layeroptions=QgsVectorFileWriter.VectorFormatOption()

QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layernew, newDatasource, "utf-8", layernew.crs(), "KML",False, None,"","",False,"",symstyle)
```

Comment: What is not working about it? What is the significance of the lines that are commented out?

Comment: TypeError: QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(): arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  overload 1: argument 7 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  overload 2: argument 4 has unexpected type 'QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem'
  overload 3: argument 3 has unexpected type 'str'

Comment: get errors above , but if just use QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layernew, newDatasource, "utf-8", layernew.crs(), 'KML') but I need add  symbology color etc.,it's fine in qgis2 , lines commented out due not in use

Answer (score 3):

There are some classes and methods you are using which don't even exist in QGIS3:

- `QgsFillSymbolV2` should be just [`QgsFillSymbol`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsFillSymbol.html)
- and likewise `rendererV2()` is just [`renderer()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsVectorLayer.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorLayer.renderer)

`QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat` is also deprecated in QGIS3. Use [`writeAsVectorFormatV2`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.22/core/QgsVectorFileWriter.html#qgis.core.QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2)
or even `writeAsVectorFormatV3` (from QGIS 3.20 onwards) instead.

```py
mySymbol1 = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color':'#ffffff','color_border': '#dddddd','width_border': 2})

myRenderer  = layernew.renderer()
myRenderer.setSymbol(mySymbol1)

layernew.triggerRepaint()

options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.driverName = "KML"
options.symbologyExport = QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(layernew, 'D:/test.kml', QgsProject.instance().transformContext(), options)

# or using QGIS 3.20 and later
# QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV3(layernew, 'D:/test.kml', QgsProject.instance().transformContext(), options)
```

For those kinds of problems in general I can strongly advise to try to get familiar with reading the API documentation of pyqgis.

Comment: thank you very much,perfect